# Change the SELECT in WHERE clause to another solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, where-clause

I want to make my query better. What opportunities that I have to change this code for a faster one?

```
SELECT sn
FROM package p
WHERE StatusID = 1
AND ( NOT EXISTS( SELECT * FROM packagedetail pd
                  WHERE pd.packageID = p.ID AND packageDetailStatus = 12 ) 
      OR ( EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM packagedetail pd
                  WHERE pd.packageID = p.ID AND packageDetailStatus = 12) 
            AND  EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM unit u JOIN unitDetail ON u.ID = ud.unitID
                   WHERE (ud.InmostPackageID = p.ID OR ud.OutmostPackageID = p.ID) 
                   AND u.UnitStateID in (8120, 8130, 8140)
                 )
         )
     )
```

( I know this is so ugly, but I want to know, how can I improve my skills )

Comment: That query isn't complete. `AND (SELECT *...)` isn't a boolean expression.

Comment: Do you want it cleaner, shorter, or faster?

Comment: Performance issues are, in general, best investigated by examining the _actual execution plan_. That will help find opportunities for better indexes as well as restructuring the query. Please see [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/) for a way to include an execution plan in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simplification that you can do is to not repeat the `NOT EXISTS` subquery again.

The below query is semantically equivalent to yours:

```
SELECT p.sn
FROM package p
WHERE p.StatusID = 1
AND (
  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM packagedetail pd 
             WHERE pd.packageID = p.ID AND packageDetailStatus = 12) 
  OR 
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM unit u JOIN unitDetail ON u.ID = ud.unitID
          WHERE (ud.InmostPackageID = p.ID OR ud.OutmostPackageID = p.ID) AND u.UnitStateID in (8120, 8130, 8140))
);
```

because:

```
(NOT X) OR (X AND Y) = (NOT X) OR Y
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that might make it easier to read:

```
SELECT sn
FROM 
    package p
    cross apply
    (select
         exists_packagedetail   =case when exists   (
                                                        SELECT * 
                                                        FROM packagedetail pd 
                                                        WHERE pd.packageID = p.ID AND packageDetailStatus = 12
                                                    ) then 1 else 0 end
        ,exists_unitdetail      =case when exists   (
                                                        SELECT * 
                                                        FROM 
                                                            unit u 
                                                            JOIN unitDetail ON u.ID = ud.unitID 
                                                        WHERE (ud.InmostPackageID = p.ID OR ud.OutmostPackageID = p.ID) AND u.UnitStateID in (8120, 8130, 8140)
                                                    )then 1 else 0 end
    ) as q1
WHERE StatusID = 1 and (q1.exists_unitdetail=1 or q1.exists_packagedetail=0)
```